# A peculiar operation on $M_2(\mathbb Z)$ which along with the usual matrix addition, makes $M_2(\mathbb Z)$ into a commutative ring with unity

Tags: linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras

For $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ c_1&d_1 \end{pmatrix}, B=\begin{pmatrix} a_2 & b_2 \\ c_2&d_2 \end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb Z)$, define

$A*B:=a_1L_1BR_1+b_1L_1BR_2+c_1L_2BR_1+d_1L_2BR_2$, where

$L_1=I_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0&1 \end{pmatrix}, L_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}, R_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1&-1 \end{pmatrix}, R_2=-I_2-R_1$.

Is there an elegant/clever way to see that $(M_2(\mathbb Z),+,*)$ forms a commutative ring with unity, where $+$ is the usual matrix addition, and $*$ acts as the multiplication?

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: There is an isomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}^{2 \times 2} \to \prod_j O_j$ a product of orders in  number fields or a subring of $M_4(\mathbb{Z})$ that you can find from the minimal polynomials

Comment: @reuns: I don't understand ... could you elaborate on your comment please ?

Comment: @IgorRivin: To tell you the truth, this is just what my professor mentioned ... I'm supposed to find a structure ...

Comment: If your professor wants _you_ to find a structure, shouldn't you be trying to do this rather than asking other people to do it? Or have I misunderstood your meaning?

Comment: @YemonChoi: Well he didn't tell to find a structure ... he just mentioned it and said verified it ... I believe there should be a structure

Comment: So, the professor just disguised a standard law (retrieved by Matt's solution) using a change of coordinates, and made an exercise out of it (check associativity, etc). Solving this kind of exercises has nothing to do with research, and is not the purpose of this site. (It's also not the purpose of MathSE to solve such exercises, when no effort is made by the OP to show one's progress.)

Comment: @YCor, I agree that solving the professor’s exercise of verifying associativity, etc, is not a research problem.  But the question was to exhibit an isomorphism to an easily intelligible structure, and I did not find that so obvious.

Comment: Just so it is clear, the question poster should refer to MathOverflow and MattF's answer when communicating the solution to anyone else.  Gerhard "The Right Thing To Do" Paseman, 2018.10.29.

Comment: Another approach: Let $G=\mathbb Z/(3)$ and $\hat G$ be the multplicative character group of $G$ i.e. the group of all characters from $G$ to $\mathbb C^{\times}$. Define a map $\psi : M_2(\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C^{\hat G}$ as $\psi(A)(\chi)=\begin{pmatrix} \chi(1) & \chi(2) \end{pmatrix} A  \begin{pmatrix} \omega \\ \omega^2 \end{pmatrix}, \forall A\in M_2(\mathbb C), \forall \chi \in \hat G$. It can be shown that $\psi$ is an injective $\mathbb C$-linear map and $\psi(A*B)=\psi(A).\psi(B)$

Comment: @YCor: I found another approach which is not just only a change of co-ordinates ...

Comment: @MattF. I agree, retrieving a standard law in disguise is not necessarily an obvious exercise, and is harder than checking associativity, etc, my mistake. Still, I don't think this is not the role of this site, especially if this has been given as an exercise by a professor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{C\times C}\rightarrow (M_2(\mathbb{R}),+,*)$ given by

$$f((1,0))=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & -1\\-1 & -1
\end{array}\right)\!/2,\ \ \
f((i,0))=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\1 & -1
\end{array}\right)\!/2\sqrt{3},
$$

$$f((0,1))=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-1 & -1\\1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\!/2,\ \ \
f((0,i))=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & -1\\-1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\!/2\sqrt{3}
$$

which I found by finding the identity for *, then finding two idempotents which add up to the identity, then finding two elements whose squares are the negatives of those idempotents.

So there is an isomorphism 
$g:(M_2(\mathbb{Z}),+,*) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z[\omega]\times Z[\omega]}$ given by

$$g\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right)
= \left(\omega,\ \omega\right)
,\ \ \
g\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right)
= \left(\omega^2,\omega^2\right)
,\\
g\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\right)
= \left(\omega, -\omega\right)
,\ \ \ 
g\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\0 & 1
\end{array}\right)\right)
= \left(\omega^2,-\omega^2\right)
$$
Here $\omega=(-1+\sqrt{3i})/2$, and there are copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the image because $1=-(\omega+\omega^2)$.

Comment: The multiplication and addition of $(\omega\mathbb Z +\omega^2\mathbb Z)\times (\omega\mathbb Z +\omega^2\mathbb Z)$ is the usual co-ordinate wise right ? So the operations on $M_2(\mathbb Z)$ is just the transport of that structure by the bijection $g$ right ?

Comment: Yes, the bijection is with (the subset of) CxC with coordinatewise addition and multiplication.